# What's a common and good penalty in optimization to ensure that values sre roughly in {0,1}?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have the simple optimization problem

$$\min_A\vert\vert Ax-x\vert\vert_2,$$

where $x$ is a given n-dimensional vector and $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix that needs to be calculated

Now this is simple to calculate abd there are a bunch of ways to efficiently do that

But now I would like that all values of $A$ are in $\{0,1\}$

I don't want to turn it into an ILP as it would make the problem NP hard
So I guess the best way is to add a penalty term to keep the solution set convex but to force values to be  very close to 0 or 1, so something like

$$\min_A\vert\vert Ax-x\vert\vert_2 +...,$$

where the penalty '...' will get very huge if one value of $A$ is far from zero and one.
After that you can just set those values close to zero equal to zero and those values close to one equal to one

So my question is - what would be a reasonable penalty to achieve that? Is there a common penalty for that?

Comment: I think a convex penalty term will, at best, force the entries of $A$ to belong to $[0, 1]$, not $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: @Johannes is this for theoretical research or practical problem? While convex ILP (QP) is NP-hard, binary ILP solvers are incredibly fast in practice (look at solvers like CPLEX, they can deal with 10K or even 100K variables with no issues (that translates up to 300x300 matrix ))

Comment: @Theo Bendit If the penalty forces the values should be exactly zero or one then of course the problem is not convex anymore but if the penalty just forces the values to be close to 0 or 1 the set of possible solutions is still convex

Comment: @AspringMat I will look into that... I'm just a bit worried because my score actually is a bit more complicated

Comment: @Johannes No, but what I meant is that if you want this penalty function to be a convex function, then the penalty between $0$ and $1$ can be no larger than the maximum penalty at $0$ and $1$, just by convexity. So, adding a convex penalty to this problem cannot punish terms equal to, say, $1/3$, more than it punishes $0$ and $1$.

Comment: What's wrong with the trivially optimal solution $A=I$

Comment: That the diagonal is equal to 0 as a condition